# AspectJ get the object which calls the method and its argument

Tags: java, spring, aspectj

I have the following aspectJ definition in my Spring configuration xml file

```
<bean id="valueLogging" class="org.beans.ValueLogging">
     <constructor-arg value="#{T(System).out}" />
</bean>

<aop:config>
    <aop:aspect ref="valueLogging">
        <aop:pointcut id="settingValue" expression="execution(* *.setValue(..)) and args(parameter, value)"/>

        <aop:after pointcut-ref="settingValue" method="logAfterSettingAValue" />
    </aop:aspect>
</aop:config>
```

Then, I have the `ValueLogging` class:

```
public class ValueLogging {

    private PrintStream stream;

    public ValueLogging(PrintStream stream) {
        this.stream = stream;
    }

    public void logAfterSettingAValue(final Object element, final String parameter, final Double value) {
        stream.println(element + " :The value " + value + " has been set to the parameter " + parameter.getName());
    }

}
```

I'm getting an initialization error. Here is part of the trace:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'networkElement' defined in class path resource [META-INF/spring/parameterChange.xml]: BeanPostProcessor before instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJPointcutAdvisor#0': Bean instantiation via constructor failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJPointcutAdvisor]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: warning no match for this type name: this [Xlint:invalidAbsoluteTypeName]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:472)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:755)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
    at com.ericsson.domain.ParameterChangeMain.main(ParameterChangeMain.java:16)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with nam
```

I think this is due to the fact that I'm not able to capture the caller of the method to give it as an argument to the `logAfterSettingAValue`method.
Any idea?